# OpenSSL error while loading RubyMine on Snow Loepard 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rubymine

I installed Rais and Ruby 2.x via RVM months ago when I was using  OSX 10.6. Today I made blunder to try installing `PhantonJS` via HomeBrew. it also tried to install `openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz` and installed too. I could not install PhantomJS as it was taking time but resta assured OpenSSL was installed. This evening when I tried to load `RubyMine` for work I got following errors:

```
10:36:04 PM Failed to load remote gems 
            Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
            Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.5/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
            /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/https.rb:22:in `'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:39:in `configure_connection_for_https'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:93:in `connection_for'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:122:in `fetch'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:337:in `request'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:231:in `fetch_http'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:266:in `fetch_path'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:296:in `cache_update_path'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source.rb:177:in `load_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:266:in `tuples_for'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:231:in `block in available_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:222:in `available_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:147:in `detect'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:165:in `show_gems'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `block in execute'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `each'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `execute'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `'
            Please check proxy settings and gem urls (show balloon)
10:36:05 PM Failed to load remote gems http://gems.github.com
            Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
            Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.5/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
            /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
            Referenced from: /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            Reason: image not found - /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin10.0/openssl.bundle
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/https.rb:22:in `'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:39:in `configure_connection_for_https'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:93:in `connection_for'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request.rb:122:in `fetch'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:337:in `request'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:231:in `fetch_http'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:266:in `fetch_path'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:296:in `cache_update_path'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source.rb:177:in `load_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:266:in `tuples_for'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:231:in `block in available_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:222:in `available_specs'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:147:in `detect'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:165:in `show_gems'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `block in execute'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `each'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/query_command.rb:109:in `execute'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
            from /Users/JhonDoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `'
            Please check proxy settings and gem urls (show balloon)
10:36:07 PM RubyMine Gem Manager
            RubyMine has detected that
            some of the gems required for 'HITS'
            are not installed
            Install missing gems
            (show balloon)
```

As you can see it is not finding required `openssl` libs. How do I sort this out?